# How to access outlook meeting details of another user from a Shareable calendar using Rest API

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create a web app whose primary task is to fetch an appointment with another user. I need to fetch an appointment on outlook calendar.

I am working with Microsoft Rest APIs directly from the web and using [npm module - msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal)
from official Azure AD.

Using this I have been able to allow the user to choose and login in to a microsoft account and then fetch the user's email details.

I however, would like the user to see the calendar details of another user (the way we can see someone's calendar availability in outlook). Basically, I need to subscribe to someone's calendar so that I can fetch latest snapshot of the calendar whenever required.

I have tried to explore various APIs in the official [wiki document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/MSAL.js-1.0.0-api-release#configuration-options) and [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations). However, I couldn't find any way of achieving it.

Am I wrong in assuming that this can be achieved ?
I have even tried to [share calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-your-calendar-in-outlook-com-0fc1cb48-569d-4d1e-ac20-5a9b3f5e6ff2), but it didn't help.

Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this or direct me to some article on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the other user has shared their calendar with the user logged into your app, then you can achieve this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars

As per the api definition, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

There are 2 scenarios where you can access another user's calendar, that is, the above, or you give the app permissions to read all users.

> There are two scenarios where an app can get another user's calendar:
>
> ```
> If the app has application permissions, or,
> If the app has the appropriate delegated permissions from one user, and another 
> user has shared a calendar with that user, or, has
> given delegated access to that user. See details and an example.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this surely helps. Are you also aware of any API  which can accept user credentials (emailId and password) and can implicitly log in a user without interactive popup behavior.